# Jquery "if" statement if viewport size X

Tags: jquery, if-statement, viewport

Apologies for my naivety, I am getting my head round JQuery and have what I think is a moderately tricky question (For me at least). My syntax skills are not yet there. (I am studying a cook book at the moment). I am going round in circles.

Site:
I am currently executing an add class with Jquery to animate some Divs when the user is in viewport. This is great with tablet and desktop but on mobile the combination 'classToAdd' (which animates) and 'ofset' looks shabby and is slow.

Looking to resolve:

Whatever the solution, I want to fire these animations "only" when the view port is greater than say 600px (or simular method) so I can disable on mobile.

Basically I want JQuery to check the that the browser window size is above 'X' band if it is to then fire the script below to fire animations.

Not sure that I am trying to do much in one snippet - asking the viewport to do more than one thing. I have tried to add and if statement from looking at examples but it will not fire.

The script I am currently using is:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.lead_image_middle').addClass("hidden").viewportChecker({
        classToAdd: 'visible animated fadeInUp',
        offset: 100

       });
});
```

Dev @  http://dfacility.com/dev.21in/index.html

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [window.matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.matchMedia):

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 600px)").matches)
```

[CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchmedia)

[polyfill](https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( screen.width > 1000 ) { do something }
```

Comment: Please offer some explanation as it's helpful not only to solve but also inform.